# Binding a field with #name not working angular 2 mac

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a form, which contains one drop field and a submit button,
I am trying to enable or disable the button on the basis of the selected value of the drop-down field.
My code looks like this.

```
<select #drop>
<option value="">Disabled</option>
<option value="1">Enabled</option>
<option value="2">Enabled</option>
</select>

<button [disabled]="!drop.value">
</button>
```

This is working fine on Safari but does not enable the button in chrome, once the selection is made, unless i click somewhere outside on the window.

Comment: And if you use an `ngModel`, does it work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to make it work with template variable you have to "angularize' it, i.e include events or attributes that are recongenized by Angular.
As for the bellow two examples:

**1.** Use `ngModel`:

```
<select #drop ngModel >
  <option value="">Disabled</option>
  <option value="1">Enabled</option>
  <option value="2">Enabled</option>
</select>
<button [disabled]="!drop.value">Button</button>
```

**2.** Make use of `change` or 'input' events:

```
<select #drop (change)="null" >
  <option value="">Disabled</option>
  <option value="1">Enabled</option>
  <option value="2">Enabled</option>
</select>
<button [disabled]="!drop.value">Button</button>
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v1gtae)